# Does Win11 still have the 3-second hotkey delay?

Tags: windows-11

Since moving to Win10 I have had problems with a 3-second delay between the pressing of a hotkey (for example, ctrl+alt+N) and the start menu item I have assigned that hotkey to (for example, Notepad) activating.

This turned out to be an extremely common problem amongst Win10 users, and with no easy fix.

Does the hotkey delay issue still persist in Win11?

Comment: I am not seeing any undue delay (faster than 3 sec)  in Windows 10 and the action is the same time  in my Windows 11 machine right here.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

"Does the hotkey delay issue still persist in Win11?"

Two years later and I now have a new PC that came with a fresh install of Windows 11. And yes, Windows 11 also has the 3 second hotkey delay.

For those still on Windows 10 who were wondering, then no this hasn't been fixed in Windows 11.